# Caching issue with Flash Player 11.7

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers, flash, osmf

**Short-version:**

Our Flash app is live-streaming video from our CDN, starting with the recent release of Flash Player 11.7

**Background:**

We have a Flash app that runs in the browser. We see the problem with IE 8, 9, 10, on Windows XP and Windows 7. Both 32-bit and 64-bit.

When our app makes a request for video to our CDN, the browser refuses to cache it, and it is causing high network traffic. Caching worked well in Flash Player 11.6.

**Issue:**

Using Fiddler, we have contrasted the HTTP requests in the good and bad cases. The only difference is that, with Flash Player 11.7, the raw request contains:

```
Pragma: no-cache
```

I realize that this is implementation specific and not supported. Note that ***we*** don't want this.

We are using the [OSMF framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Media_Framework) (version 2.0) and have access to the source.

**Code:**

The specific code (abstracted considerably):

```
resource = new URLResource(url);
player = new MediaPlayer();
factory = new DefaultMediaFactory();
element = factory.createMediaElement(resource);
player.media = element;
```

**Question:**

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Ideas include:

- suggested patches to OSMF
- settings for Flash Player. is it possible that IE now considers FP 11.7 a proxy ?
- other ideas. CDN config?

Sadly, using a different browser is not an option for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the following worked for us:

Change this:

```
var playerResource:URLResource = new URLResource(url);
```

to this:

```
var playerResource:StreamingURLResource = new StreamingURLResource(url); 
playerResource.streamType = StreamType.LIVE_OR_RECORDED;
```

In detail, we know that OSMF 2.0 did not change between Flash 11.6 and Flash 11.7. However, it seems as though the interpretation of the default value of `streamType` did change, possibly by accident. Flash 11.7 treats the default as though it is a "live stream" and does not cache.

By specifying `streamType` explicitly, things go back to normal. There is no "Pragma: no-cache" in the HTTP request. Our app calls out for the video once, and then it is cached. This fix also works in the original env, Flash 11.6.